# How to transform a Map<Set<A>, B> into a Map<A, Set<C>>

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, set, java-stream

I'm having a problem with finding an optimal solution (which is not multiple usage of `forEach`).

I have objects `A`, `B` and `C`. Object `B` contains set of objects `C (i.e.` B->Set`).

I'm being provided with a `Map<Set<A>, B>` which I need to turn into a `Map<A,Met<C>>`.

Is there any function in streams library that provides this particular solution?

The solution I came up with for now is to process this map through `forEach`.

With each iteration, I'm merging sets of `C` for each `A` in the map `Map<A,Set<C>>`. Here is outline of solution (there is a lot of things happening inside, the b->c is shortcut of whats happening).

With creating `Map<A,Set<C>>` where in each iteration I'm providing a merger of previous sets for each of them. Here is the outline of solution(there are a lot of things happening inside, the b->c is shortcut of what's happening).

```
Map<A, Set<C>> aSetCMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Set<A>, B> entry : setABMap.EntrySet()) {
  var setA = entry.getKey();
  var setC = b.transformC();
  setA.forEach(item -> aSetCMap.merge(item, setC,
    (current, added) -> Streams.concat(current.stream(), added.stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

The solution I came up with is a wonky way to do it in O(n^3) time. The thing I'm using it needs high performance, thus my question.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about the time complexity, but [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) will help syntactically: `EntryStream.of(map).flatMapKeys(Set::stream).flatMapValues(b -> b.getC().stream()).groupingTo(HashSet::new)`

Comment: The actual code is a lot longer and more complex, it's the part that I find requires the most of optimization. My question is to further research this particular part. The Map<A, Set<C>> is actually a object that wraps around key and value, effectively it acts like the Map collection inside Streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten each entry `Map.Entry<Set<A>, B>`. And associate each object `A` with a `Set<C>` extracted from the object `B`.

After that, apply `collect()` by using a flavor of `Collectors.toMap()` which takes three arguments: a *keyMapper*, a *valueMapper* and a *mergeFunction* (which is needed to combine *sets* mapped to the same object `A`)

```
Map<Set<A>, B> source = getSourceMap();

Map<A, Set<C>> result =
    source.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getKey().stream()
                    .map(a -> Map.entry(a,  entry.getValue().getC())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                  Map.Entry::getValue,
                                  (set1, set2) -> {set1.addAll(set2); return set1;}));
```

The approach shown above is applicable if the `Set<C>` could be obtained from an object `B` in a constant time. Here I rely on your words:

> `B` contains set of objects `C`

If this action entails an additional processing (I see a method `transformC()` in your code) and creates a new set after each invocation of `transformC()`, then for each entry in the source map it must be done only once (*i.e. use multiline lambda*).

In regard to time complexity of stream-based solution, your expectation of performance improvement will ***not*** come true (assuming that there's no logical fault in the iterative solution).

**Note**, the situation when a mutable object (`Set<A>`) is used as a key is vicious by itself and could cause incorrect behavior.